# Does setting a manual seed in torch and numpy propagate into all imported scripts, nested functions, etc?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a script structure like this:

main.py -> launcher_util.py: run_experiment(experiment, ...) -> experiment.py: experiment(...)

In main.py, I call:

```
import torch
import numpy
torch.manual_seed(1)
np.random.seed(1)
```

But when looking at multiple runs of my experiments, the results are not identical. The only two sources of randomness come from PyTorch and Numpy (i.e. due to random environment variables generation in OpenAI Gym), yet the experiment result plots are not identical. Why?